# Installing Microsoft.speech for c# microsoft 2013

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-speech-api

So I downloaded the Microsoft speech sdk at this address 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

I ran the installer and am having trouble figuring out how to reference it in visual studio so that i can include it in my c# program using visual studio 2013

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this assembly/reference to your c# project

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Assembly\Microsoft.Speech.dll.**